# Report and Dashboard - Show This Month vs This Month Last Year Next To Each Others Using Column Chart

Tags: reporting, dashboard, column

I'm building a report to compare **all months this year** vs **all months last year**. Right now, the `Column Chart` only shows ascending order. Example: Jan 22, Feb 22, March 22,... Jan 23, Feb 23.

I wonder if there is a way to show Jan 22 and Jan 23 next to each other so it will give users a clear comparison.

My solution:

- I tried with Joined Report but it did not work.

Another solution:

- I created 2 Dashboards, 1 for last year and 1 for this year and place them next to each other.

Thanks so much!
[image: What I have]
What I have
[image: What I would love to have]
What I'm aiming for

Comment: This is possible but far from trivial. Start with https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_combination_charts_using.htm&type=5&language=en_US and then go through https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/rd-summary-formulas .

Comment: Thank you for your comment! @identigral 

Not sure if we can make it next to each other but I found another workaround using Row-level Formula and Stack to stack it. This month will stack on this month last year.

Comment: I'm trying to do this same thing. How were you able to separate your data through row-level formula in SFDC report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is you just need to:

1. **Group Rows** with a `Year field`. Eg: Close Year.
2. **Group Column** with a `Date field`. Eg: Close Date.
3. Sort column **Close Date** by **Calender Month in Year**.